# NoClassDefFoundError using Kony Studio

Tags: javascript, android, amazon-web-services, ffi, temenos-quantum

Recently while using kony studio,
I have integrated Amazon SDK using ffi, but on firing the event it  pops up a message saying `noClassDefFoundError`:

> Failed resolution of :
>   Lcom/amazonaws/auth/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider;
>
> JS Stacktrace:
>
> at init(analytics.js:2:15)

The analytics.js looks as below:

```
function init(){

    analytics.init("someId","pool");

}
```

I am passing these parameters to the native implementation using FFI.

What could it be the cause of this error?

Answer (score 0):

Please check in you have KonyWidgets.jar and android-support jar part of your FFI jar. They must only be used as reference when you build the FFI wrapper but should not be part of the actual jar used in FFI mapping. 
Please refer Android FFI guidelines doc [here](http://docs.kony.com/konylibrary/studio/kony_platform_app_design_guidelines/Default.htm#FFI.htm#Android2%3FTocPath%3DCoding%2520Guidelines%7CForeign%2520Function%2520Interface%2520(FFI)%7C_____2).